# Show that $span({v_1,...v_n})=span({v_1,...,v_{n-1},w})$

Tags: analysis, vector-spaces

This is what's given:
$v_1,...v_n,w ∈ V$ and $v_1+...+v_n+w=0$

then I need to show that $span({v_1,...v_n})=span({v_1,...,v_{n-1},w})$

I could think of a way to show that this is true if I was sure that every $v_i$ and w were $0$, but they arent, right?
Would using this be helpful?: 
$span(v_1,...,vn) = \left\{x*(v_1,...v_n)|x∈ℝ\right\}$

I really don't know how to start this, any hints would be great, I'm also pretty sure that I could understand this by seeing the solution, or at least a part of it. I have a few problems of this kind and feel like solving this would help me understand the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$span\{v_1,\dots,v_n,w\}=\{\sum_{j=1}^n\alpha_jv_j+\beta w| \alpha\in\mathbb R^n,\,\beta\in \mathbb R\},$$
but $w=-\sum_{j=1}^nv_j$, hence

$$span\{v_1,\dots,v_n,w\}=\{\sum_{j=1}^n(\alpha_j-\beta)v_j| \alpha\in\mathbb R^n,\,\beta\in \mathbb R\}=\{\sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_j v_j| \alpha\in\mathbb R^n\}=span\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$$

Note that both $\alpha_j$ and $\alpha_j-\beta$ cover the whole line $\mathbb R$.